# Memory Leak in Android Phone

Tags: android, browser, memory-leaks

I have seen some memory leak in my phone.

Steps :

1. Open Browser (Home Page : www.google.com). It will fetch the Page.
2. Select Back Key to come out from browser (close).
3. Repeat the same steps (1-2) for 5 times.

Observer following data by "adb shell dumpsys meminfo PID (of browser) :

First Time (when open browser first time - After Step 1):

Applications Memory Usage (kB):
Uptime: 428816 Realtime: 434932

```
** MEMINFO in pid 899 [com.android.browser] **

                  native   dalvik    other    total
          size:    24296     6727      N/A    31023
     allocated:    24241     3955      N/A    28196
          free:       54     2772      N/A     2826
         (Pss):     3455     2259    30025    35739


(shared dirty):     2064     1772     7444    11280

  (priv dirty):     3388      548    21116    25052

 Objects

           Views:        0        ViewRoots:        0
     AppContexts:        0       Activities:        0
          Assets:        3    AssetManagers:        3
   Local Binders:       34    Proxy Binders:       28
Death Recipients:        1
 OpenSSL Sockets:        0
```

Second Time (After Step - 4) Opening - Closing of Browser 5 times :

Applications Memory Usage (kB):
Uptime: 473642 Realtime: 479758

```
** MEMINFO in pid 899 [com.android.browser] **

                  native   dalvik    other    total
          size:    45616     7559      N/A    53175
     allocated:    45322     4850      N/A    50172
          free:       29     2709      N/A     2738
         (Pss):     4602     2301    51988    58891

(shared dirty):     2060     1736     7440    11236

  (priv dirty):     4536      584    42360    47480

Objects

            Views:        0        ViewRoots:        0
      AppContexts:        0       Activities:        0
           Assets:        3    AssetManagers:        3
    Local Binders:      113    Proxy Binders:       47
 Death Recipients:        1
  OpenSSL Sockets:        0
```

Could you please help us to find out what data here shows which information (like what is Size, Allocated, free, Local Binders etc) and where in above data it is showing that there is memory leak.

New to all these analysis so asking basic questions :-(

Please help me for this.

Thanks
Rke

Answer (score 0):

You know, I don't really see a memory leak here. The most common way to get memory leak is to have references to Activity which had to be destroyed. Anyway, there is a way to search for leak, there is a good article in Android developers blog about memory analysis in Eclipse with MAT and there is also a video from Google IO-2011. Try it, and maybe you'll find what's wrong.

Comment: But if we see above values like Size, Allocation etc its getting increased in second table, though we are just opening Browser which should be in Paused State (when we close the browser) and should be Restarted when we again Open it. It should not allocate another set of memory or if it is, it should de-allocate it (or delete it while closing app).
Could you please see if above data is showing any memory leak.

Comment: We have tested it on 2 set of phone, in one phone let say "A", the size and allocation data (as in above table) is not getting increased much (only small change is there) but for phone "B", it is more (above data is for Phone "B")......because of that I assume that there is some memory leak.

Could you please help us to give some pointers for this problem from given data.

Comment: As I said, the only way for you to know it is to use memory analyzer. As for numbers: from what I see, there is considerable growth in native memory. There are number of options:1. You use native malloc 2. On pre-Honeycomb you don't get bitmap pixel data collected. If you don't use neither of that - that numbers are not your fauult.

Comment: Hi Mighter,  Thanks for your comments.....Can you please suggest some methods by which we can analyze memory leaks in NATIVE CODE (of Android).....we have got these results on Android Phone (GINGERBREAD)....if you can suggest some MEMORY ANALYZER....which can help us....we are totally new in this area.......Thanks in Advance......Rke

Comment: I guess you can't analyze that.